# Entity Framework is looking for the principle end of an association and it should not be

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I did spin up a IOC (Ninject) with UOW and repository with all the pocos etc.. , but after an issue with my "Get"  I figured that I would step back and get a quick POC working

So all that I am doing I attempting to ONLY talk to this "Skill" poco

```
private DataContext _db = new DataContext();
```

**Calling method that causes error**

```
public List<Skill> GetAllSkills()
{

   var query = (from s in _db.Skills
                     select s).ToList();


   return query;
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
```

Auto-generated  poco (ado.net wizard)

```
public partial class Skill
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Skill()
    {
        InternSkills = new HashSet<InternSkill>();
        Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    public int Skillid { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SkillName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2500)]
    public string SkillDesc { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InternSkill> InternSkills { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

**My error**

{"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Data.Entities.AssignmentTime' and 'PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Data.Entities.Assignment'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."}

**UPDATE**

I see that the poco of `Project` in the Skill poco

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

**Code for Project poco**

```
public partial class Project
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Project()
    {
        Assignments = new HashSet<Assignment>();
        ProjectInternTimes = new HashSet<ProjectInternTime>();
        Skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
    }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public int? StatusId { get; set; }

    public int? OfficeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContactNameLast { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContactNameFirst { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2500)]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ProjectDesc { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDateSpecific { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }

    public int? EstimatedWeeks { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateRequested { get; set; }

    public int? JobTitleId { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }

    public virtual JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectInternTime> ProjectInternTimes { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are Assignment and AssignmentTime? Those aren't in the code you posted...

Comment: This is just super annoying ,...  Ok so I see that this property  `public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }`   is there in which that Project POCO contains it.    Nightmare

Comment: Can you also add the code of your Project POCO? That would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: just did,  thx   ,  i could add the assignment and assignmenttime if that helps more

Comment: Yep, adding those would also help. It's a long chain to find exactly why EF is mad.